# manipulate dynamically generated tk-inter widgets without global variables

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

This code of a minimal example is functional:

```
from tkinter import *

textbox =str()

def openpopup():

    popupwindow = Toplevel(root)
    global textbox
    textbox = Text(popupwindow, height=20, width=40,font="Courier")
    textbox.pack()

    textbox.delete(1.0, END)
    textbox.insert(1.0,"start")

    Button(popupwindow, text="do it", command=changepopup).pack()

def changepopup():
    global textbox
    textbox.delete(1.0, END)
    textbox.insert(1.0,"changed text")


root = Tk()
Button(root, text="open", command=openpopup).pack()
mainloop()
```

my goal is to open a popup dynamically on userinput and then have various gui elements interact.
I managed to do this using global. I've read using global variables should be avoided.

What is the recommended way of going about this? Can I avoid using globals? I am aware that this is an issue of scoping, this is how I came up with this "solution". I am not so familiar with OOP but I have a hunch this might be a solution here.

Answer (score 1):

The object-oriented way would be to create a `class` representing "popup" objects. The class' initializer method, `__init__()`, can create the popup's widgets as well as act as a storage area for the contents of the `Text` widget. This avoids needing a global variable because methods of class all has an first argument usually call `self` the is instance of the class.

Any data needed can be stored as attributes of `self` and can easily be "shared" all the methods of the class.

The other primary way to avoid global variables is by explicitly passing them as arguments to other callables — like `main()` does in the sample code below.

Here's an example based on the code in your question:

```
from tkinter import *


class Popup:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        popup_window = Toplevel(parent)
        self.textbox = Text(popup_window, height=20, width=40, font="Courier")
        self.textbox.pack()
        self.textbox.insert(1.0, "start")

        btn_frame = Frame(popup_window)
        Button(btn_frame, text="Do it", command=self.do_it).pack(side=LEFT)
        Button(btn_frame, text="Close", command=popup_window.destroy).pack(side=LEFT)
        btn_frame.pack()

    def do_it(self):
        self.clear()
        self.textbox.insert(1.0, "changed text")

    def clear(self):
        self.textbox.delete(1.0, END)


def main():
    root = Tk()
    Button(root, text="Open", command=lambda: Popup(root)).pack()
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. can you elaborate why "self.clear()" is part of the init method?

Comment: @Nivatius: It's there because of the `textbox.delete(1.0, END)` you have in the `openpopup()` function in your own code — I was just translating what you have in my example. It's probably not necessary in either case since the `Text` widget is already empty at that point.

Answer (score 1):

> **Question**: Can I avoid using globals?

Yes, consider this `OOP` solution without **any** `global`.

---

Reference:
- [9.5. Inheritance](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance)
- [class-and-instance-variables](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables)
- [Dialog Windows](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-dialog-windows.htm)

---

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import tkSimpleDialog

class Popup(tkSimpleDialog.Dialog):
    # def buttonbox(self):
        # override if you don't want the standard buttons

    def body(self, master):
        self.text_content = ''
        self.text = tk.Text(self)
        self.text.pack()
        return self.text # initial focus

    def apply(self):
        self.text_content = self.text.get(1.0, tk.END)

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        btn = tk.Button(self, text='Popup', command=self.on_popup)
        btn.pack()    

    def on_popup(self):
        # The widget `Popup(Dialog)`, waits to be destroyed.
        popup = Popup(self, title='MyPopup')
        print(popup.text_content)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    App().mainloop()
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I will study the linked meterial for python 3 I needed to change the following: the import from tkinter import simpledialog

and the command needs to be command=lambda: self.on_popup()

also I get an error when clicking okay.

Comment: @Nivatius: Yes , should be `self.on_popup`, no `lambda` needed and Yes `from tkinter import ...`

Answer (score 0):

The global you created, `textbox` is unnecessary. You can simply remove it from your program. and still get the same behavior

```
# textbox = str()
```

I hope my answer was helpful.